# Replace each } with a }\n in a huge (12GB) which consists of 1 line?

Tags: bash, logging, sed, logstash

I have a log file (from a customer). 18 Gigs. All contents of the file are in 1 line.
I want to read the file in logstash. But I get problems because of Memory. The file is read line by line but unfortunately it is all on 1 line.

I tried split the file into lines so that logstash can process it (the file has a simple json format, no nested objects) i wanted to have each json in one line, splitting at `}` by replacing with `}\n`:

```
sed -i 's/}/}\n/g' NonPROD.log.backup
```

But `sed` is killed - I assume also because of memory. How can I resolve this? Can I let `sed` manipulate the file using other chunks of data than lines? I know by default `sed` reads line by line.

Comment: You may want to consider using `jq` to process your file in a streaming fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following uses only functionality built into the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

# as long as there exists another } in the file, read up to it...
while IFS= read -r -d '}' piece; do
  # ...and print that content followed by '}' and a newline.
  printf '%s}\n' "$piece"
done

# print any trailing content after the last }
[[ $piece ]] && printf '%s\n' "$piece"
```

If you have logstash configured to read from a TCP port (using `14321` as an arbitrary example below), you can run `thescript <NonPROD.log.backup >"/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/14321"` or similar, and there you are -- without needing to have double your original input file's space available on disk, as other answers thus far given require.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for `RT`:

```
$ printf 'abc}def}ghi\n' | awk -v RS='}' '{ORS=(RT?"}\n":"")}1'
abc}
def}
ghi
```

with other awks:

```
$ printf 'abc}def}ghi\n' | awk -v RS='}' -v ORS='}\n' 'NR>1{print p} {p=$0} END{printf "%s",p}'
abc}
def}
ghi
```

I decided to test all of the currently posted solutions for functionality and execution time using an input file generated by this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++)printf "foo}"; print "foo"}' > file1m
```

and here's what I got:

1) [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44855812/1745001) (both awk scripts above had similar results):

```
time awk -v RS='}' '{ORS=(RT?"}\n":"")}1' file1m
```

Got expected output, timing =

```
real    0m0.608s
user    0m0.561s
sys     0m0.045s
```

2) [shell loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44851783/1745001):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash

# as long as there exists another } in the file, read up to it...
while IFS= read -r -d '}' piece; do
  # ...and print that content followed by '}' and a newline.
  printf '%s}\n' "$piece"
done

# print any trailing content after the last }
[[ $piece ]] && printf '%s\n' "$piece"

$ time ./tst.sh < file1m
```

Got expected output, timing =

```
real    1m52.152s
user    1m18.233s
sys     0m32.604s
```

3) [tr+sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44851869/1745001):

```
$ time tr '}' '\n' < file1m | sed 's/$/}/'
```

Did not produce the expected output (Added an undesirable `}` at the end of the file), timing =

```
real    0m0.577s
user    0m0.468s
sys     0m0.078s
```

With a tweak to remove that final undesirable `}`:

```
$ time tr '}' '\n' < file1m | sed 's/$/}/; $s/}//'

real    0m0.718s
user    0m0.670s
sys     0m0.108s
```

4) [fold+sed+tr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853720/1745001):

```
$ time fold -w 1000 file1m | sed 's/}/}\n\n/g' | tr -s '\n'
```

Got expected output, timing =

```
real    0m0.811s
user    0m1.137s
sys     0m0.076s
```

5) [split+sed+cat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44851772/1745001):

```
$ cat tst2.sh
mkdir tmp$$
pwd="$(pwd)"
cd "tmp$$"
split -b 1m "${pwd}/${1}"
sed -i 's/}/}\n/g' x*
cat x*
rm -f x*
cd "$pwd"
rmdir tmp$$

$ time ./tst2.sh file1m
```

Got expected output, timing =

```
real    0m0.983s
user    0m0.685s
sys     0m0.167s
```

Answer (score 2):

You can running it through `tr`, then put the end bracket back on at the end of each line:

```
$ cat NonPROD.log.backup | tr '}' '\n' | sed 's/$/}/' > tmp$$
$ wc -l NonPROD.log.backup tmp$$
    0 NonPROD.log.backup
   43 tmp10528
   43 total
```

(My test file only had 43 brackets.)

Comment: Simple, but it works (except for inserting an extra `}` at the end of the file if there isn't one there already). I'd suggest taking the `cat` out of the pipeline -- `<NonPROD.log.backup tr '}' '\n' | sed 's/$/}/'` will be ever so slightly more efficient.

Comment: Tired it -- got about a 1% decrease in time.

Comment: Yup. It'll be a much bigger difference if the program is something like `sort` that can parallelize when given a seekable file handle rather than needing to read front-to-back with a FIFO. (`cat file |` doesn't provide direct access to `file`, but only to streamed output from `cat`). Another example is `wc -c` -- with a real file handle it can finish in constant time no matter how large the file is, with a FIFO it has to read the whole thing unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Split the file to say 1M chunks using `split -b 1m file.log`
2. Process all the files `sed 's/}/}\n/g' x*`
3. ... and redirect the output of `sed` to combine them back to a single piece

The drawback of this is the doubled storage space.

Comment: There's going to be doubled storage no matter what if one wants to serialize output to disk and the transform being performed generates output larger than the original input -- while `sed -i` is writing a temporary output, that output needs to go *somewhere*. One can do a truly in-place transform only if the output is equal-size or smaller. If you deleted the original file as soon as `split` were done, you could avoid going over double+1mb (plus the size of the extra newlines themselves).

Comment: (...well -- "only" was a little strong -- Linux has some extensions that allow specific blocks in a memory-mapped file to be retroactively be deleted and made sparse, if using an appropriate filesystem, but that's quite the corner case).

Answer (score 0):

another alternative with `fold`

```
$ fold -w 1000 long_line_file | sed 's/}/}\n\n/g' | tr -s '\n'
```

Comment: You get newlines on places where you do not need them.